# Combine stringsdict & Localizable.strings file

Tags: ios, localization

Earlier iOS supported Localizable.strings. In iOS10, for handling pluralisation etc iOS introduced new format "stringsdict". Can we just have stringsdict file for all localisation or do we have to maintain multiple files.

Comment: You should be able to have only stringdict, but they are quite verbose and since XCode doesn't show highlight its syntax, it's quite harder to read than .strings for common stuff.